# collect a sequence of paged results ( 776 pages ) from REST API ( JSON response) and insert final result into DB SQL or create csv file

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, stream, reactive

I am consuming a Rest API which is exposing 6212514 rows from SQL Server Database. The response of REST API is JSON which represents the database rows.

To call this API REST and get the hole data , I am using in each iteration a pagination through parameters **offset** and **limit** :
exemple:

- call 1 :

`http://localhost:8080/myapi/dwcopa/getSlice?**limit**=8000&**offset**=1&buCd=XXX`

- call 2 :

`http://localhost:8080/myapi/dwcopa/getSlice?**limit**=8000&**offset**=2&buCd=XXX`

.
.
.

- call 760 :

`http://localhost:8080/myapi/dwcopa/getSlice?**limit**=8000&**offset**=760&buCd=XXX`

*limit* is the number of returned objects by each call to the API REST and *offset* is the page number

Example : limit = 8000 and offset 1: Call will return the first 8000 json objects of the page number 1

To get 6212514 rows i need to do 776 paginations  / call to the client API REST (= 6212514 /8000)  to get all results which I need to store either  in database SQL server table or make a csv file with these 6212514 rows.

Actually I am using this code in a Spring Boot application (version 2.5.1)  (standalone Spring Boot not REST API)  ( Java 11 / Spring webflux / Webclient ) to consume the client RESt API and fetch all data by pagination :

In a service JAVA class :

My Spring **Webclient** to consume the REST API :

```
public DwCopaServiceImpl() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .codecs(codecs ->codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(memSize) )
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, API_MIME_TYPE)
                .build();
    }
```

I am using **Reactive Mono** to non blocking the call API and iterating all pagination util the response.isLast() is false ( this field indicates that this page of REST API is the last )

**DwCopaEntity** is an entity which presents a row ( JSON ) and contains many String fields  :

```
public Mono<List<DwCopaEntity>> getItems() {
        String url = "/dwcopa/getSlice?limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset+"&buCd="+BUCD;

        return fetchItems(url).expand(response -> {
            if (**response.isLast()** ) {
                return Mono.empty();
            }
            offset += 1 ;
            
            return fetchItems("/dwcopa/getSlice?limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset+"&buCd="+BUCD);
        }).flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getContent())).collectList();
    }

private Mono<ResponseApiNeo> fetchItems(String url) {

    System.out.println(url);
    return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToMono(ResponseApiNeo.class);
}
```

After that to get all results :

```
writeStreamToFile ( myService.getItems().block().parallelStream().map(data -> data.toString()), "C:\\Users\\myfolder\\Documents\\optfile.txt") ;
```

I am new to *webflux* and *Webclient*. This solution takes 25 min to get all Api REST pages and creates a file txt which is not validated by the client:

Is there a better solution multi threading to:

- paginate a hole rest API REST ( 760 pages):  (large data response : JSON 6 GB in total )
- Insert all response into SQL Database or create a csv file ?
- Performance is crucial ( max 5 min to get all data)
- Should I correct my code to get faster / add Threads ?

Many Thanks for your helps .

Answer (score 0):

Does your API return a count (either on its own or via a property of the paginated response)?

If so (and your data is returned in a consistent order) you could divide the total by the page size and make chunks of concurrent requests (doing 100% of the requests concurrently may load your service and db excessively and result in it taking longer than doing all the requests sequentially).

You would then need to reconstitute all responses into the right places.

I'm assuming you have no control over the API you are consuming, else I'd suggest turning that into a streaming endpoint (but then you have issues of long running operations, resuming after interruptions etc.)

Comment: Thanks @jeremyt  , yes   My API return a count  via a property of the paginated response   , you could divide the total by the page size and make chunks of concurrent requests (doing 100% of the requests concurrently may load your service and db excessively and result in it taking longer than doing all the requests sequentially).  why ?

Comment: Assuming the API you're calling doesn't have some kind of rate limiting (getting HTTP 429 responses would indicate that it does), you will have a bottleneck. The API will have to divide its resources between requests, which will mean each request takes longer than if it was executed on its own. You might even find that the bottleneck is your connection to the API if the bandwidth required is too high.

Comment: Thanks , So what's the the solution in term of code source ?